# macOS Big Sur: Unexpected product version 11.1. How to patch perlbrew?

Tags: macos, perl, perlbrew

I just updated my Macbook Air from 10.15 to 11.1, and then tried to install perl 5.32 with perlbrew:

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.32.0
Installing /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.32.0/perl-5.32.0 into ~/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.0

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:

  tail -f ~/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.32.0.log

Installation process failed. To spot any issues, check

  /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/build.perl-5.32.0.log
```

and the build log shows:

```
[...]
Which of these apply, if any? [darwin]

*** Unexpected product version 11.1.
***
*** Try running sw_vers and see what its ProductVersion says.

##### Brew Failed #####
```

Fortunately, this issue has been fixed in the Perl development branch, see [Add 11.x support for darwin.sh](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/17946). So how can this fix now be backported to Perl 5.32.0 and applied with perlbrew?

Can [patchperl](https://github.com/bingos/devel-patchperl) be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like I just had to run:

```
$ perlbrew install-patchperl

/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/bin/patchperl already exists, are you sure to override ? [y/N] [N] y

patchperl is installed to

    /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/bin/patchperl
```

and then rerun

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.32.0
```

Comment: Does this resolve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65297237/589924)?

Comment: @ikegami No it does not. I added an [issue](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/18406)

Comment: Oops, what I claimed was a meta ticket was a actually a pull request, and a closed (merged) one at that. I've updated my earlier answer to reference your ticket.